# Stm32 optimization exercise

Tags: c, stm32

I am writing a program to turn on leds on a stm 32 board (model KAmeleon-STM32L496ZGT6).

I have LEDs 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

When I run the program it goes from 0 to 7 than bounces back and goes 7 to 0 and so on.

When I click joystick(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_15), it changes direction.

My code below works, but I have a feeling that it could be clearer and/or more optimized. Is it possible to rewrite `main` (I would rather not rewrite the `setSingleLED` function).

```
void setSingleLED(int which)
{
    if(which > 7 || which < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    GPIO_TypeDef * ports[8] = {GPIOC, GPIOC, GPIOC, GPIOC, GPIOE, GPIOD, GPIOE, GPIOE};
    uint16_t pins[8] = {GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_6};
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ports[i], pins[i], GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ports[which], pins[which], GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
int main(void)
{
    int zmienna=0;
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_7, RESET);
    int current_diode = 0;
    int dir = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        if (current_diode < 0)
        {
            zmienna=0;
            current_diode = 1;
            dir=1;
        }
        else if (current_diode > 8)
        {
            zmienna=1;
            current_diode=7;
            dir=1;
        }
        setSingleLED(current_diode);
        //HAL_Delay(100);
        unsigned int i = 0;
        int ischange=0;
        while (i < 5000)
        {
            if((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_15) == 0)&&(ischange==0))
            {
                ischange=1;
                if(dir==1)
                {
                    dir= -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    dir= 1;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(zmienna>0)
        {
            current_diode -= dir;
        }
        else
        {
            current_diode += dir;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use `setSingleLED()` AND not change it? Then you are probably lost. Could you create a new function? One which assumes a single LED being set at `which`, resets it and sets an adjacent one, according to a second parameter `direction`? That would avoid writing a lot of values to registers which are already in there, i.e. save the loop.

Comment: Yes i can create new function.

Comment: What then has you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas how to improve the code:

- Move the `ports` and `pins` array outside the function as to ensure they are only initialized once
- `i == which` to select the LED state. That way there is no need to check if `which` is within range.
- Merge `zmienna` and `dir` into a single variable `dir` as it doesn't any difference if the direction needs to be changed due to user interaction or due to reaching the upper or lower bound.
- Remove the loop to 5000, which seems to be a way to debounce the button. This shouldn't be needed as the loop contains a `HAL_Delay()` to control the speed of the LED movement. If it's not sufficient, add more `HAL_Delay()` within the *if* clause for detecting the button press.
- Use `dir = -dir` to change the direction (instead of an *if* clause)
- Rearrange code such that update of `current_diode` is closer together

```c
static GPIO_TypeDef * ports[8] = {GPIOC, GPIOC, GPIOC, GPIOC, GPIOE, GPIOD, GPIOE, GPIOE};
static uint16_t pins[8] = {GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_6};


void setSingleLED(int which)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ports[i], pins[i], i == which ? GPIO_PIN_SET : GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_7, RESET);
    int current_diode = 0;
    int dir = 1;

    while (1)
    {
        // light up selected LED
        setSingleLED(current_diode);

        // check if button has been pressed
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_15) == 0)
        {
            dir = -dir;  // change direction
        }

        // update selected LED position
        current_diode += dir;
        if (current_diode < 0)
        {
            current_diode = 0;
            dir = 1;
        }
        else if (current_diode > 7)
        {
            current_diode = 7;
            dir = -1;
        }

        // delay to control speed of effect
        HAL_Delay(100);
    }
}
```